# Include a jsp page in another page

Tags: jsf, richfaces

All of my JSF pages contain the following imports

```
<h:head>
<title>My Registration Page</title>
<link href="stylesheet/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.png" />
<script language="javascript" src="script/script.js"/>
```

Not i dont want to copy and paste all these lines in the head element of my xhtml page;but want to include only a single page, so i want to remove all these lines from the head and put them into another file and then just include that file.

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or SF 2.x?

Comment: @Luiggi: there's a `<h:head>`, so it's impossible that OP is using JSP. He is apparently confusing technologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)